# how to split the values of a mysql column delimited by a value into another column?

Tags: mysql

I have a column containing house numbers and unit numbers. I need the house numbers and unit numbers in two different columns.

The unit numbers are contained within brackets. The following is the sample data:

```
Column 1           Column 2
85 (Unit A)
85 (Unit B)
86
87 - 89 (Unit A)
```

The desired result is as follows:

```
Column 1          Column 2
85                Unit A)
85                Unit B)
86      
87 - 89           Unit A)
```

The values are delimited by '('

How do I do this?

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET column2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_table.column1,'(', -1), 
column1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_table.column1,'(', 1)
```

The result of this query is as follows:

```
Column 1          Column 2
85                Unit A)
85                Unit B)
86                86
87 - 89           Unit A)
```

I don't need the '86'  Column 2 to be updated! I want it to remain as null if there is no '(' How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For selection,

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX( Col1 , '(', 1 ) AS C1,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( Col1 , '(', 2 ),'(',-1) AS C2  from Tablename
```

For update

```
Update TableName set Column1= SUBSTRING_INDEX( Column1 , '(', 1 ) ,Column2= SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( Column1 , '(', 2 ),'(',-1) ;
```

Comment: The query works partly but I should to update 'Column2' before we update 'Column 1', otherwise the original column1 values are changed before updating 'column2'. The problem is the column 2 values are updated to column one values even if there is no delimter for that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table SET column1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_table.column1,'(', 1),  column2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_table.column1,'(', -1)
```

Comment: The query works partly but I should to update 'Column2' before we update 'Column 1', otherwise the original column1 values are changed before updating 'column2'. The problem is the column 2 values are updated to column one values even if there is no delimter for that row.